# String Manipulation in R data frames

Tags: r

I just learnt R and was trying to clean data for analysis using R using string manipulation using the code given below for Amount_USD column of a table. I could not find why changes were not made. Please help.

**Code:**

```
csv_file2$Amount_USD <- ifelse(str_sub(csv_file$Amount_USD,1,10) == "\\\xc2\\\xa0", 
str_sub(csv_file$Amount_USD,12,-1),csv_file2$Amount_USD)
```

**Result:**

> \\xc2\\xa010,000,000
>
> \\xc2\\xa016,200,000
>
> \\xc2\\xa019,350,000

**Expected Result:**

```
10,000,000
16,200,000
19,350,000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code, but maybe there is a more compact way:

```
vec <- c("\\xc2\\xa010,000,000", "\\xc2\\xa016,200,000", "\\xc2\\xa019,350,000")

gsub("(\\\\x[[:alpha:]]\\d\\\\x[[:alpha:]]0)([d,]*)", "\\2", vec)
[1] "10,000,000" "16,200,000" "19,350,000"
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I hope I find a compact and easier to understand solution as I have just started doing R.

Answer (score 1):

A compact way to extract the numbers is by using `str_extract` and negative lookahead:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(vec, "(?!0)[\\d,]+$")
[1] "10,000,000" "16,200,000" "19,350,000"
```

How this works:

- `(?!0)`: this is negative lookahead to make sure that the next character is not `0`
- `[\\d,]+$`: a character class allowing only `d`igits and commas to occur one or more times right up to the string end `$`

Alternatively:

```
str_sub(vec, start = 9)
```

Comment: Glad to hear this. If you'd kindly consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer

Answer (score 0):

There were a few minor issues with your code.

The main one being two unneeded backslashes in your matching statement. This also leads to a counting error in your first `str_sub()`, where you should be getting the first 8 characters not 10. Finally, you should be getting the substring from the next character after the text you want to match (i.e. position 9, not 12). The following should work:

```r
csv_file2$Amount_USD <- ifelse(str_sub(csv_file$Amount_USD,1,8) == "\\xc2\\xa0", str_sub(csv_file$Amount_USD,9,-1),csv_file2$Amount_USD)
```

However, I would have done this with a more compact `gsub` than provided above. As long as the text at the start to remove is always going to be `"\\xc2\\xa0"`, you can simply replace it with nothing. Note that for `gsub` you will need to escape all the backslashes, and hence you end up with:

```r
csv_file2$Amount_USD <- gsub("\\\\xc2\\\\xa0", replacement = "", csv_file2$Amount_USD)
```

Personally, especially if you plan to do any sort of mathematics with this column, I would go the additional step and remove the commas, and then coerce the column to be numeric:

```r
csv_file2$Amount_USD <- as.numeric(gsub("(\\\\xc2\\\\xa0)|,", replacement = "", csv_file2$Amount_USD))
```

Comment: Thanks that worked with minor change in above code like you said I did not escaped backslashes so I added 1 backslash at both end i.e. 4 on both sides and just a small change from second str_sub call from 12 to 11. Though I agree that your way of gsub is compact. Thanks again for that knowledge.